# Disponibilidad datepicker (mysql,php)

Tags: php, mysql, datepicker

Hola estoy haciendo un sistema de reservas en el cual necesito mostrar en mi datepicker las fechas que están ocupadas y las que no.

la tabla reservas es asi (esta resumida)

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists reservas(

id_reserva integer(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_cliente integer,
id_residencial integer(20),
id_habitacion integer(20),
llegada date,
salida date,
PRIMARY KEY (id_reserva), 
FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente) REFERENCES clientes(id_cliente),
FOREIGN KEY (id_residencial) REFERENCES residenciales(id_residencial),
FOREIGN KEY (id_habitacion) REFERENCES habitaciones(id_habitacion)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

en mi formulario tengo los input de llegada y salida

```
<input style="height: 31px;" id="datepicker2" class="form-control" name="llegada" >
```

...

```
<input style="height: 31px;" id="datepicker3" class="form-control" name="salida">
```

y para el datepicker 
tengo este codigo

```
<script>
$(function() {
var eventDates = {};
        eventDates[ new Date( '12/04/2016' )] = new Date( '12/05/2016' );
        eventDates[ new Date( '12/06/2016' )] = new Date( '12/06/2016' );
        eventDates[ new Date( '12/20/2016' )] = new Date( '12/20/2016' );
        eventDates[ new Date( '12/25/2016' )] = new Date( '12/25/2016' );

        $( "#datepicker3" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths:[2,2],
        showButtonPanel: true,
            firstDay: 1,
      beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
                var highlight = eventDates[date];
                if( highlight ) {
                     return [true, "event", "highlight"];
                } else {
                     return [true, '', ''];
                }
             }
        });

    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">    
.event a {
    background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, 0.45) !important;
    background-image :none !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
</style>
```

esto me muestra el calendario con los días en rojo, pero los días que yo definí ya en la función :

```
 eventDates[ new Date( '12/04/2016' )] = new Date( '12/05/2016' );
            eventDates[ new Date( '12/06/2016' )] = new Date( '12/06/2016' );
            eventDates[ new Date( '12/20/2016' )] = new Date( '12/20/2016' );
            eventDates[ new Date( '12/25/2016' )] = new Date( '12/25/2016' );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces lo que busco es que desde mi tabla `reservas` pueda obtener un rango de fechas entre `llegada` y `salida` (anteriormente ya seleccionada la `id_habitacion`), y ese rango aparezca en rojo y no se pueda seleccionar en el datepicker . 
eh buscado y bastante, pero no eh podido juntar o coordinar la información con mi código. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre como deshabilitar los dias en esta pagina
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331543/disabling-specific-dates-from-html-datepicker-jquery

solo cambie los dias para un ejemplo mas reciente espero te ayude

```js
/** Days to be disabled as an array */
var disableddates = ["12-12-2016", "13-12-2016", "14-12-2016", "14-12-2016"];


function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
    return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
  }


$(function() {
  $("#date").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <input id="date" type="text">


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: sii gracias si ayudó, ahora solo falta rescatar  un rango de fechas, desde 2 fechas de la BD (llegada,salida), estoy en eso.. y haber si alguien también lo postea acá. :)

Comment: de nada diana, te recomiendo revisar la documentacion oficial https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ , tambien podrias ayudar dandole como respuesta aceptada oh votar a fover la respuesta te lo agradeceria